# Are there alternatives to Ubuntu Private Cloud?

Tags: cloud-hosting

In particular, alternatives that:

1. Do NOT use VMs
2. Provide small host OS image size

(in reply to Steven Xu's comment)

Ubuntu Private Cloud features:

1. Linux based
2. Provides web administration
3. (AFAIK) Free

Comment: Are you sure this is programming related?

Comment: Could you specify what aspects/features of the Ubuntu Private Cloud you'd like to find elsewhere? I ask because what I identify as the primary usefulness of the Cloud, location-agnostic access to a private set of files, certainly requires a host (which will either be a VM or a dedicated physical server). Perhaps your situation is different and you're looking for particular things. If you narrow them down, I'm sure folks would be better able to help you out!

Comment: so, you don't want to manage VM's.  what do you want?

Answer (score 10):

> 1) Do NOT use VMs

How about a TV that doesn't show images, or a plane that doesn't fly?

Clouds are about nothing BUT VMs - anything else is called "a bunch of ill-used hardware".

Comment: That's your opinion. I want servers to boot from network with a special linux image which allow processes to be uploaded and executed. No need for VM.